# Sort alphanumeric data in natural order in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of data I wish to sort in natural order, however it sorts in lexographical order. How can I sort in a natural order?

The data I have, which gets sorted as such:

```
A1
A10
A11
A12
A13
A14
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
B1
B2
B3
B4
```

The order I would like for it to be sorted in:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
A10
A11
A12
A13
A14
B1
B2
B3
B4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the original data as listed in your post resides in range A2:A19. Place the following formula in B2 of an otherwise open range B2:B (or in the Row-2 cell of any other open column where you want the sorted results):

`=SORT(A2:A19,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A19,"\D+"),1,TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A19,"\d+")*1,"000"),1)`

This formula assumes that the numeric portion of your strings is never longer than three digits. If it does exceed, just change `000` to include the number of zeros that match the max digits that may appear in the numeric portion of your strings.

Of course, you'll need to adjust the `A2:A19` to match the actual range of the original data in your sheet.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @Erik, may be `=SORT(A2:A19,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A19,"\D+"),1,value(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A19,"\d+")),1)` doing so you will not need to adjust the format 000

Comment: Agreed, Mike. Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IDs that could potentially contain multiple numbers, like `level8_text23`, you may want to use this:

`=SORT(A2:C99,REGEXREPLACE(A2:A99,"\d+$",""),1,TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A99,"\d+$")*1,"0000000"),1)`

Where `A2:C99` is the range of the data you want to sort together.
And `A2:A99` is column with the IDs.

PS: `"0000000"` should be enough numbers for most use cases.